# How to test whether input is a string or int

Tags: c++

I'm building a calculator and the user is able to input different strings for different operations `cout << endl << endl << "+,-,*,/,^,pi,sqrt,clear,quit,help" << endl;` The program needs to know if it is a string so then it can run `pi,sqrt,clear,quit,help`. If it is an float it needs to know that so it can run the simple arithmetic and it also needs to save the float for the operation.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#include "PageFormat.h"
#include "Help.h"
#include "MathFunctions.h"


int main()
{
//VARIABLES
bool mathMode;
string operatorType;


//OBJECTS
Help ho;                    //object for the help class
MathFunctions mfo;
PageFormat pfo;


//INTRO
cout << "****** CalcPal ******" ;

mathMode = true;

while (mathMode == true){
cout << endl << endl << "+,-,*,/,^,pi,sqrt,clear,quit,help" << endl;
cin >> operatorType;


if (operatorType == "+"){
    mfo.add();
}

if (operatorType == "-"){
    mfo.subtract();
}

if (operatorType == "/"){
    mfo.divide();
}

if (operatorType == "*"){
    mfo.multiply();
}

if (operatorType == "^"){
    mfo.power();
}

if (operatorType == "pi"){
    mfo.pi();
}

if (operatorType == "sqrt"){
    mfo.squareRoot();
}


if (operatorType == "clear" || operatorType == "Clear"){
    pfo.clearPage();
}

if (operatorType == "quit" || operatorType == "Quit"){
    mathMode = false;
}

if (operatorType == "help" || operatorType == "Help" ){                   //Triggers the help menu
    ho.helpMenu();
}

}
}
```

This is the MathFunctions cpp file

```
#include "Help.h"
#include "PageFormat.h"
#include "MathFunctions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

MathFunctions::MathFunctions()
{
}


int MathFunctions::add(){                   // Addition Function


    float num1;
    float num2;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "+" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    float answer = num1 + num2;
    cout << "= " << answer;
}

int MathFunctions::subtract(){              //Subtraction Function


    float num1;
    float num2;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "-" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    float answer = num1 - num2;
    cout << "= " << answer;
}

int MathFunctions::divide(){                //Division function


    float num1;
    float num2;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "/" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    float answer = num1 / num2;
    cout << "= " << answer;
}

int MathFunctions::multiply(){              //Multiplication function


    float num1;
    float num2;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "*" << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    float answer = num1 * num2;
    cout << "= " << answer;
}

int MathFunctions::power(){                 //Power function


    float num1;
    int num2;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "^" << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    float num1Holder = num1;
    for (int powerTower = 1; powerTower < num2; powerTower ++){

        num1 = num1 * num1Holder;
    }
    cout << "= " << num1;
}

int MathFunctions::pi(){
    float num1;
    double pii;
    pii = 3.14159;

    cin >> num1;
    cout << "*" << endl << "pi" << endl;
    float answer = num1 * pii;
    cout << answer;
}

int MathFunctions::squareRoot(){
    float num1;

    cin >> num1;
    float answer = sqrt(num1);
    cout << answer;

}
```

This is the MathFunctions header file

```
#ifndef MATHFUNCTIONS_H
#define MATHFUNCTIONS_H


class MathFunctions
{
public:
    MathFunctions();
    int add();
    int subtract();
    int multiply();
    int divide();
    int power();
    int pi();
    int squareRoot();

private:
    float num1();
    float num2();
    float answer();
    double pii();
    int x;
    int y;


};

#endif // MATHFUNCTIONS_H
```

There are two other files also, but they make no difference here so I would just rather not overbloat this question.

As you can probably see, right now the user has to enter what kind of operation they want to use, then enter the two numbers. It would be much more convenient to be able to enter a number then the operation, but also have the option to enter a command like `help` or `clear`. If there is some way of telling if a string is a float, then turning it into a float that would be very helpful.

Comment: Typically, you would attempt to convert the input to a number. If it fails then it's not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the input as string. You can convert into double using `atof`. If you are using C++ 11, you can use `stof` as well.